# How to make a single UIViewController Right To Left (RTL) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, right-to-left

I need to make one of my view controllers RTL in my application. I found a way that makes whole application RTL but I don't want tab bar and other view controllers to become RTL. Any solution would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `semanticContentAttribute` for `view` in your view controllers as:

```
view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: Because answer shouldn’t be questions and it’s better to format code for readability